# Implementing a countdown timer in a pipe with additional service to update component when timer finishes

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, momentjs, setinterval

I'm showing a date/time countdown on the screen with my Angular app. It's a countdown from a specific date and time.

Running it every second is killing my CPU with Google Chrome.
It might be the moment() lib that has some effect, but not sure yet.
I might try it without moment, to see if that helps.
[image]

Is there a better (more efficient) way to do this?

Here is my code

```js
calculateTimeRemaining(endDate: Date, timeZone: string, eventId: number) {
  setInterval(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById("event-" + eventId);
    if (element) {
      const currentDateUtc = moment().utc();
      const endDateUtc = moment(endDate).utc(true);
      endDateUtc.tz(timeZone);
      const dif = moment.duration(endDateUtc.diff(currentDateUtc));
      const hours = dif.hours();
      const minutes = dif.minutes();
      const seconds = dif.seconds();
      if (hours < 1) {
        element.innerHTML = minutes + ' m ' + seconds + ' s';
      } else {
        element.innerHTML = hours + ' h ' + minutes + ' m ' + seconds + ' s';
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<span id="event-{{event.id}}" class="float-right yb-color">{{calculateTimeRemaining(event.datePendingUtc, event.yogabandTimeZoneId, event.id)}}</span>
```

**EDIT (solution)** - I've implemented a countdown timer in a pipe (as recommended) to solve this issue. I'll include the full code for the pipe below and how I call it. I also have a service that is being used to send notifications to my component when the timer is up so I can perform other actions.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EventService } from 'src/app/core/services/event.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'timeRemaining'
})
export class TimeRemainingPipe implements PipeTransform {
  eventId: number;
  expired = false;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  /**
   * @param futureDate    should be in a valid Date Time format
   *                      e.g. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.msz
   *                      e.g. 2021-10-06T17:27:10.740z
   */
   public transform(futureDateUtc: string, eventId: number): Observable<string> {
    
    this.eventId = eventId;
    /**
     * Initial check to see if time remaining is in the future
     * If not, don't bother creating an observable
     */

    if (!futureDateUtc || this.getMsDiff(futureDateUtc) < 0) {
      console.info('Pipe - Time Expired Event: ' + eventId);
      return of('EXPIRED');
    }
    
    return timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        takeWhile(() => !this.expired),
        map(() => {
            return this.msToTime(this.getMsDiff(futureDateUtc));
        })
    );
  }

  /**
   * Gets the millisecond difference between a future date and now
   * @private
   * @param   futureDateUtc: string
   * @returns number  milliseconds remaining
   */
   // Z converts to local time
   private getMsDiff = (futureDate: string): number => (+(new Date(futureDate + 'Z')) - Date.now());


   /**
    * Converts milliseconds to the
    *
    * @private
    * @param msRemaining
    * @returns null    when no time is remaining
    *          string  in the format `HH:mm:ss`
    */
   private msToTime(msRemaining: number): string | null {
       if (msRemaining < 0) {
           console.info('Pipe - No Time Remaining:', msRemaining);
           this.expired = true;
           this.eventService.expired(this.eventId);
           return 'EXPIRED';
       }

       let seconds: string | number = Math.floor((msRemaining / 1000) % 60),
           minutes: string | number = Math.floor((msRemaining / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
           hours: string | number = Math.floor((msRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

       /**
        * Add the relevant `0` prefix if any of the numbers are less than 10
        * i.e. 5 -> 05
        */
       seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
       minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
       hours = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;

       return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
   }

}
```

```html
<span class="float-right yb-color">{{(event.dateUtc | timeRemaining: event.id | async}}</span>
```

Here is the service

```js
export class EventService {
  private subject = new Subject <any> ();

  expired(eventId: number) {
    this.subject.next(eventId);
  }

  expiredEvents(): Observable <any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}

// how it's called in the component

this.eventService.expiredEvents().subscribe(eventId => {
  console.info('Service - Expired Event:', eventId);
  // do something now w/ expired event
});
```

Comment: Is this component set to onPush? I’m not surprised that this is killing your browser. Don’t call this already pretty inefficient code from your template, it will trigger multiple times per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance, don't call any function inside Angular template because it will run in every change detection.

This article describes the issue very well https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

We could change your implementation using pure pipe

`time-remaining.pipe.ts`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'timeRemaining',
})
export class TimeRemainingPipe {
  transform(event: any): any {
    // put implementation here
    // return time remaining
  }
}
```

I believe in the pipe, you could remove `const element = document.getElementById("event-" + eventId);` part.

`component.html`

```html
<span id="event-{{event.id}}" class="float-right yb-color">{{ event | timeRemaining }}</span>
```

Reference:
https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: ok let me try it. So what you're saying is move it to a pipe and that should fix the CPU issue?

Comment: ya that worked well! Thanks!

Comment: awesome mate! Maybe you could share the final code in your original post so other devs can learn from this issue. 